# What are some resources that analyze "how centralized Bitcoin really is"

Tags: decentralization

Are there any blogs that track the centralization in Bitcoin? Is it growing, or is Bitcoin becoming less centralized over time?

E.g. I believe mining pools have become somewhat less centralized in the last two years. At some point the [hash power distribution](http://blockchain.info/pools) had 1-2 pools that controlled over 50% of the network - now the largest piece in the hash power pie is "Unknown" (possibly solo miners).

This is nice - but it still doesn't answer the question, as I don't really have the historic data to compare with. Other aspects of centralization worth tracking over time is Mt. Gox volume, the number and power distribution between core developers, and ownership of various community assets such as bitcointalk & the wiki.

As an answer I would want to get some threads/blogs that analyze this information and post updates - the answer in this case can't be a static analysis of the present situation (it wouldn't be a good fit for this Q&A format, as such answers tend to get stale).